# oracle yyyyiw glitch

Tags: sql, oracle11g, date-format

I'm on oracle 11.2 it's december 30 2014.
the query

```
select to_char(sysdate ,'YYYYIW') from dual
```

returns
`201401` instead of `201501`

Am I wrong or is it Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the ISO year as well as the ISO week, use the [IYYY format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#sthref430):

```
select to_char(sysdate,'IYYYIW') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'IYYYIW')
-------------------------
201501
```

Mixing ISO and non-ISO will give you odd results. You can see the difference this makes with something like:

```
with t as (
  select date '2014-12-19' + level as dt
  from dual connect by level <= 18
)
select to_char(t.dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as dt,
  to_char(t.dt, 'YYYYWW') as normal,
  to_char(t.dt, 'YYYYIW') as iso_week,
  to_char(t.dt, 'IYYYIW') as iso
from t
order by t.dt;

DT         NORMAL ISO_WEEK ISO  
---------- ------ -------- ------
2014-12-20 201451 201451   201451 
2014-12-21 201451 201451   201451 
2014-12-22 201451 201452   201452 
2014-12-23 201451 201452   201452 
2014-12-24 201452 201452   201452 
2014-12-25 201452 201452   201452 
2014-12-26 201452 201452   201452 
2014-12-27 201452 201452   201452 
2014-12-28 201452 201452   201452 
2014-12-29 201452 201401   201501 
2014-12-30 201452 201401   201501 
2014-12-31 201453 201401   201501 
2015-01-01 201501 201501   201501 
2015-01-02 201501 201501   201501 
2015-01-03 201501 201501   201501 
2015-01-04 201501 201501   201501 
2015-01-05 201501 201502   201502 
2015-01-06 201501 201502   201502
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this one I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Oracle's glitch.

`YYYY` returns the year with four places regardless of what follows or preceeds it. Since `sysdate` is in the year `2014`, it's correct for Oracle to return `201401`.

Comment: Thank you.I'll guess I have to live with it/ program it myself.

Comment: Maybe `to_char(sysdate, 'yyyyww')` (which returns `201452`) is more intuitive?